# My object does not spawn to the designated area in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I have an object called "round" which should spawn at the artillery (or fall at least since I turned off collision).

Whenever I try to run the script the round does not spawn at the designated area but instead, nothing happens. How do I fix this?

This is the code from the script:

```
local artilerry = script.Parent
local gun = artilerry.Gun
local round = game.ServerStorage.Round

local roundclone = round:Clone()
roundclone.Parent = game.Workspace  

roundclone.Position = gun.Position
```

I made some local variables then made a clone from a pre-existing object called the "roundclone". This should always spawn at the artillery's gun but it doesn't. The original "round" is at the ServerStorage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned that you turned off collision, does that mean that `roundclone.CanCollide` is false?

Comment: if your object is a part set round.Anchored to false, if it is model move it with MoveTo() void

Comment: I think roundclone.cancollide is false too. Since I copied and pasted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that I took an eternity to answer but I actually found a simple solution 2-3 months ago.

I simply had to access the position of artillery to create a new instance of a round.

```
local artillery = game.Workspace.Artillery
local gun = artillery.Gun

-- Solution 
function CreateRound()
    local round = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
    round.Shape = "Ball"
    round.Position = gun.Position
    round.Name = "Round"
    
    local function CloneRound()
        while true do
            wait(1)
            CreateRound()
        end
    end 
    
    CloneRound()
end
```

CreateRound()

I renamed artilerry to artillery because apparently, I can't spell properly.

Answer (score 0):

If `round` is a model then make sure it has a valid `PrimaryPart` and use

```
Model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(gun.Position))
```

If your model/part has CanCollide false then make sure Anchored is set to true or else the mode/part will just fall through everything and get destroyed by the void.

---

If you have any questions make feel free to ask. If this solved your issue please make sure to mark this as the answer so other people benefit from it.

Comment: I wonder if roblox changed their physics simulator thingy or did I just missed something. Thx

Comment: @colappse Could you mark my answer as the correct answer so other people know it's solved and it helps them too? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for slow replies but I will check the solutions out.